# Implement a SQL query in Crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, oracle10g

I want to generate a report in Crystal Reports and I am very new to it. I am unaware of how to manipulate the Crystal Report. I made a SQL query which gives me all the required output from the Oracle(10g) database. But I need to convert it to be used inside Crystal Reports.

This is the SQL query which gives me required output:

```
SELECT 
    ins.ins_name,ins.ins,crdi.ct, crdi.bn,
    sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'PO', 1, 0)) POCount,
    sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'CN', 1, 0)) CNCount
FROM
    crdh, crdi, ins
WHERE 
    crdh.crd_st IN ('PO','CN') 
    and crdi.bn in (select unique bn from crdh)
    and crdh.bn = crdi.bn 
    and crdi.ins = ins.ins
GROUP BY 
    ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name, crdi.ct
ORDER BY 
    ins.ins, crdi.bn;
```

When I implemented the above query I got the following error:

a) When I put the above query in *Database|Show SQL Query...*, the following part of the query is removed:

```
sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'PO', 1, 0)) POCount,
sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'CN', 1, 0)) CNCount
GROUP BY ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name,crdi.ct
```

b) When I added a group for ins.ins, Crystal reports adds a lots of spaces in the report.

c) How can I print the value of POCount and CNCount in the crystal report?

I am also adding the screenshot of the output for better understanding.

[image: Output of the above SQL query]

**There can be multiple BN for one INS and for one BN there are multiple CNs and POs. Like INS 3 has two BN ('123456','789012') and there are 3 POs and 0 CN in BN '123456', but there is only one CN in BN '789012'.** I hope this is helpful to replier.

Please help me to get a report same as the output of the above mentioned query. Thanks in advance.

I got the following result :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont implement sum in query instead implement it in crystal. so change the query like this.

```
SELECT ins.ins_name,ins.ins,crdi.ct, crdi.bn,
      cardh.crd_st,cardh.crd_st
FROM crdh, crdi, ins
```

Add above query in crystal report `command` when you make a connection to the report.

Now for your report to display in the required format.

1. Create a formula `@PO`

   `if cardh.crd_st= 'PO'
   then 1
   else 0`
2. Create formula for `CN`

   `if cardh.crd_st='CN'
   then 1
   else 0`
3. Place above formula in detail
4. Create a group by `ins.ins_name`
5. Place all your columns in group footer and at the same time take sum for the formulas `@po` and `CN`
6. As you are using where condition in query to get that condition in CR. Implement your where clause in `Select Expert ---> Record Selection Formula`, If you are not comfortable then try implement the where clause in query itself.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Siva-I have added my response in your reply

Comment: In this case after `ins.ins_name` group add another 2 groups `INS` and `BO` and take the summary in the required group but don't forget to place the Po and CN formulas in detail and take summary

Comment: @Siva- I followed the steps you have mentioned in your reply and i almost reach to my destination the only problem that Crystal report shows the count is increasing by one in each row. But I need the final count of CN and PO in one row. I put the sum of formula po and CN in detail and create a group by crdi.bn. Please help me.

Comment: @Siva- What do you mean by take summery?

Comment: Take the count in first group or report footer. your problem will be solved.

Comment: By using the formulas cn and po in details you will be getting 1's and 0's so take the summary of that column in group or report footer and supress details section

Comment: @Siva- I have kept INS.INS and CRDI.BIN in group and take the sum of the formulas cn and po using Running Total field. But still I got same result. I am sending a screenshot in question. I just want one row which is marked on red rectangle.

Comment: @Siva- I also want to remove the space between rows

Comment: Why r u taking running total just take the sum. Right click on the field and go to insert summary that will solve your problem

Comment: @Siva- I hope you understand my requirement.

Comment: What is the section in the screenshot where you able ro view multiple rowa

Comment: @Siva- I want just single row in the report for one BN like I marked in red rectangle. I need to put field or formula in the summary?

Comment: Hide the section shown in screenshot and place all fields in footer section..now you will seee only one row

Comment: @Siva- Its u not me:)